# Installing Azure SDK 2.7.0 After installing 2.7.1 and missing a version reference

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-sdk-.net

The project was created with a local install of Azure SDK 2.7.0.  One of the libraries is versioned to a Azure Reference of 2.7.0.0, which is apparently not available from the Azure 2.7.1 release.

Specific Error (While accessing Azure KeyVault):

```
        Message "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"    string
```

Visual Studio 2013 (5)
AzureSDK 2.7.0

Windows 10

It looks like this Window's 10 AzureSDK 2.7.1 doesn't install some dependencies required for Key Vault's in the Azure Cloud.

Suggetions for workarounds> appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As of current date the issue is an issue with Azure Key Vault Management products and the combination of Visual Studio 2013 & Windows 10 & Azure SDK 2.7.X.

One solution is to develop on Windows 7 (this works fine).  Or perhaps Windows 8, as users of this OS were not seeing the same side effect.